# System.Net.NetworkCredential can't authenticate to get file on Windows

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis-10

Let me explain my situation: I have 2 server running Windows Server 2019, and both of them have IIS v10 installed.

- server1 is IP 192.168.1.54
- server2 is IP 192.168.1.55

both servers are part of a workgroup.

On Server2 have some web that run on iis and have some picture that server1 need to read.

Folder picture on Server2 permission is everyone full control.

And I run script in PowerShell on Server1 like this:

```
$path = "D:\share_local\test.jpg"
$url = "\\192.168.1.55\share_object\test.jpg"
$username = "192.168.1.55\Administrator"
$password = "P@ssw0rdshare"
$cli_web = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$cli_web.UseDefaultCredentials = $False
$cli_web.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$cli_web.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
$data = $cli_web.DownloadString($url)
```

I get an error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The user name or password is incorrect.
>   "
>   At line:9 char:1
>   + $cli_web.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
>
> Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The user name or password is incorrect.
>   "
>   At line:10 char:1
>   + $data = $data.DownloadString($url)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

I'm very sure that User and password is correct but it still show incorrect. and I write python script to get file for prove that user and password is correct and it work fine code is below.

```
from io import BytesIO
import tempfile
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

userID = 'Administrator'
password = 'P@ssw0rdshare'
client_machine_name = 'localpcname'

server_name = 'servername'
server_ip = '192.168.1.55'

domain_name = 'domainname'

conn = SMBConnection(userID, password, client_machine_name, server_name, domain=domain_name, use_ntlm_v2=True,
                     is_direct_tcp=True)

conn.connect(server_ip, 445)

shares = conn.listShares()

attr = conn.getAttributes('share_object', 'test.jpg')
file_obj = BytesIO()
file_attributes, filesize = conn.retrieveFile('share_object', 'test.jpg', file_obj)
with open("test.jpg", "wb") as outfile:
    # Copy the BytesIO stream to the output file
    outfile.write(file_obj.getbuffer())
print ("download finished")
conn.close()
```

however I must used System.Net.WebClient in .net for my web on iis.

For summary I have question why

```
$cli_web.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
```

is not working. Please give me advice

Thank you

Comment: Can you try giving the username as `Administrator` or `.\Administrator` ?

Comment: As an aside: Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_, as needed for `-ArgumentList`).

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but since you're targeting an SMB share, you can try to (temporarily) create a drive with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) and then simply use `Copy-Item` to get the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet works perfectly, there is something wrong with the PS script.
Please refer to the below link.

```
$path = "test.JPG"
$url = "file:\\10.157.19.131\\share\"
$username = ".\administrator"
$password = "abcde12345!"
$cli_web = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$cli_web.UseDefaultCredentials = $false
#$cli_web.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
#$cli_web.DownloadFile($url,$path)
Set-Content mytest.JPG -Value $cli_web.DownloadData($url+$path) -Encoding Byte
```

About Powershell Set-Content command.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7
Here are some related discussions.
[Using WebClient to access local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074555/using-webclient-to-access-local-files)
[Write bytes to a file natively in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855705/write-bytes-to-a-file-natively-in-powershell)